# What Action of Matrix Means

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, definition

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/10466/1044836

In this post, it states that, for a matrix D that maps a vector of function values to a vector of derivative function values

> It[null space] is not just a vector space, though: it comes equipped with an action of D...

Could someone explain what action means in this context?
I tried to look it up, but I got the definition of a group action. Is there some kind of connection?

Thanks

Comment: The $D$ there is not a matrix, it is the operator $d\over dx$.